# How to detect if an application has been closed / exited

Tags: android

I have 2 service running in background.. if `Service 1` is closed, `Service 2` will start up `Service 1` again, and vice versa, 
the problem is, I want to know how to detect if that service is closed or exited.

Answer (score 1):

The [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi.. I want something like the one in [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) 
.. the method onTerminate() .. to detect if the application is terminated, but it only works for emulator ...